# Methods based on capabilities of class versus methods based on altering self?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I'm new to OOP and I'm trying to create a series new classes that add a tiered account status. Let's say the classes are `Supervisor`, `Admin`, `User`.

The first option I see is, to make a class for each of the above namespaces. Then each class has methods that utilize the capabilities of that class. So `Supervisor` can `.revokeAdminAccess()`.

The second option I see is, to make a class for each of the above namespaces. Then each class only performs actions based on itself. So the `Admin` class has a `.revokeAccess()` method, where you can pass in an  instance of `Supervisor and authorize within the`.revokeAccess()` method.

I was watching this [video from Dan Schafer on graphQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etax3aEe2dA) where they show the functionality of a `TodoItem` class that regulates access to a `.gen()` method that accepts a `viewer` argument and will authenticate using the second option described above.

**What is a better practice for creating classes, option one or option two?**

Comment: And what is your question, exactly?

Comment: Note that JavaScript [does not really have classes in classical sense](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), only objects and prototypical inheritance.

Comment: @Oriol what is a better practice for creating classes, option one or option two.